# Nested for loops- javascript: please explain why the first index iterate after I declare the inner for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested

My code works but I don't know why it does. The starting index on my outer loop is 2 and I have console logged it right after creating the outer for loop to confirm. The condition of the inner for loop is such that the code runs as long as its current index is less than the current index in the outer for loop. In my example: factor < number. I consoled logged the indexes of the outer loop (console.log(number)), right after creating the inner for loop just to confirm.

The first 'number' that is printed is 3 and I expected it to be 2 at this point, as there isn't any code  I've written to change that index. Could someone please explain what am I missing here.

```js
let show_primes = limit => {
  for (let number = 2; number <= limit; number++) {
    console.log(number); //2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

    let is_prime = true

    for (let factor = 2; factor < number; factor++) {
      console.log(number); //3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7...
      console.log(factor); //2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2,

      if (number % factor === 0) {
        is_prime = false
        break
      }
    }
    if (is_prime == true) console.log(number)
  }
}
show_primes(10)
```

Comment: ‘_The first 'number' that is printed is 3_’ I’m seeing `2`.

Comment: "*The first 'number' that is printed is 3 and I expected it to be 2 at this point*" if you mean the `console.log` in the inner loop, then it cannot be `2` because `factor < number` - `2 < 2` is `false`, so the inner loop is not executed the first time around. Only when `number = 3` and above.

Comment: [If it helps, here are the labelled logs](https://jsbin.com/sufagep/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: You have actually answered my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because factor=2 and number=2 and 2 is not smaller than 2,because of it it will not come into inner lope at first
you have to write factor <= number
Then your code show 2 ,I think you understand well ..